# add id to empty array of object using setState

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this very long code to simply generate incremental id

```
addItem = () => {
  const { items } = this.state

  const ids = items.map(item => item.id)

  const max_id = ids.length > 0 ? Math.max(...ids) : 0

  items.push({id: max_ids + 1})

  this.setState({ items })
}
```

Any better way to avoid mutation or shorter code? Above code is working, items is set to `[]` as init but above code is too long in my opinion.

Tried this but it starts with zero which is not I want

```
addItem = () => {
  const { items } = this.state
  this.setState({
    items: [
      ...items,
      { id: items.length > 0 ? Math.max(...items.map(item => item.id)) + 1 : 0 }
    ]
  })
}
```

Not sure where is the problem.

Comment: Your ternary is returning 0 in the case of an empty array - if that is not what you want you could change that to any other value for the starting value

Comment: @Tony what if I don't want to put anything in my initial array?

Comment: I think I get it, `{ id: items.length > 0 ? Math.max(...items.map(item => item.id)) + 1 : 1 }`

Comment: Yeah, that will start with an empty array, until you call `addItem` at which point it will add an ID of 1